# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'run'

Tags: python, attributes

Please, Help! I'm just learning and I don't understand what my mistake is

```
class Client:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.session()
        self.session.headers = {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 YaBrowser/20.6.2.197 Yowser/2.5 Yptp/1.23 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*',
            'Accept-Language': 'ru',
        }
    
def run(self):
    text = self.load_page()
    self.parse_page(text=text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = Client()
    parser.run()
```

Comment: Indentation is important in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to indent `run` inside `Client`

```py
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    
    def run(self):
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = Client()
    parser.run()
```

there are several tutorials online, please search for your problem thoroughly online before posting here. This is a very basic problem